# OpenCart 2 - VQmod Extensions not appearing

Tags: opencart2.x, vqmod, opencart-module

Getting nowhere on my own - help appreciated.

I'm new to Opencart, and have 2.0.3.1 installed.
Installed VQmod so I could install [Flexible Menu](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=22754), so the menu would work on phones.

Went to site/vqmod/install, and it has done - now tells me it's "already Installed"
But after installing the Menu mod I can't find it anywhere - uploaded the Upload folder's contents via ftp to the folder the shop (and VQmod) are in - and nothing has changed.
Tried this with a number of different menu mods, and still nothing.

Hoping someone with more knowledge of OC2 can see where I might be going wrong.
Help Appreciated!

Comment: What is the version of your vqmod? Have you checked for any error in log file i.e in `vqmod/logs` folder?

Comment: VQmod 2.5.1
And the logs folder is empty